# Excel VBA - website is hiding element using script (MSXML)

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, xml-parsing, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to **scrape** email id from this website https://www.construction.co.uk/c/689533/3d-structural-detailing-services-limited but website is somehow hiding email from scraping bot.

Need help in updating VBA code to get email from website or let me know if you have any alternative to do this.

HTML of website is

```
<div class="compInfoDetail">
<script>document.write(emrp('ufsftb/cfotpo.tifuumfA4etet/dp/vl','construction.co.uk'));</script>
<a href="mailto:teresa.benson-shettle@3dsds.co.uk?subject=Contact from construction.co.uk">
teresa.benson-shettle@3dsds.co.uk
</a></div>
```

VBA Code is

```
Sub construction_uk_contact_xml()
Dim IE As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim HTMLBody As MSHTML.HTMLBody
url = Selection.Value
Set IE = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
IE.Open "GET", url, False
IE.Send
While IE.ReadyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Wend
Set HTMLDoc = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Set HTMLBody = HTMLDoc.body
HTMLBody.innerHTML = IE.responseText
Set infos = HTMLBody.getElementsByClassName("compInfoSection")
For Each info In infos
    If info.getElementsByTagName("div")(0).innerText = "Email" Then ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = info.getElementsByTagName("div")(1).outerHTML
Next
Set IE = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Email address that you look for in that site is not avilable in page source (`Ctrl + U`). It is generated dynamically. Try using IE or Selenium to grab that.

Comment: Tried selenium, its working fine and giving emails but taking much more time 10sec while MSXML take 0.5sec (but not able to get email, as it load dynamically)